# OWIN username & password exposing as SAML

Tags: asp.net, owin, saml-2.0

We have a an ASP.NET site using OWIN that stores a username\password in the DB and a client has ask if a third party system can authenticate against our data using an ADFS\SAML approach. Can we expose the data held to mimic ADFS\SAML?

Would anyone have a suggestion of how this could be possible? or even better an example of where this has been done?

Thanks

Jake

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a 3rd party accessing your data by authenticating somewhere else and then passing a SAML token?

They would be using ADFS?

The problem is that your credentials are in a DB and ADFS requires the credentials to be in AD.

So you would have to be a SAML IDP and federate with ADFS.

This requires you to be the server side of SAML. Most libraries out there are for the client side of SAML.

So you could look at products like shibboleth, IDaaS e.g. Auth0 or commercial stacks e.g. ComponentSpace.

A diagram would be useful to clarify exactly what the use case is.